# DOM not update properly on removing items from top or middle angular FormArray reactive forms - angular17

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular17

I've tried to implement a reactive form with formArray in angular17. I encountered this issue when you removed one item from the formArray from the top or from the middle.
here's the [stackbiz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-h5gqq3?file=src%2Fmain.ts) for the issue reproduction.

reproduction path:

1. put some values in the film fields.
2. click the add film button to add another film to the form.
3. put some other values in the newly added film fields.
4. click on the remove film button under the first film fields.
5. observe the values in the film fields, the removed film field values are still showing on the dom. but in the below json where I display the form values are updated correctly.

I try to use ApplicationRef.tick(), ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges(), and updateValueAndValidity() as other similar issues suggested, but no luck. try to use `trackBy`, but it doesn't do the trick also. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ApplicationRef, ChangeDetectorRef, Component } from '@angular/core';
import {
  FormArray,
  FormBuilder,
  FormControl,
  FormGroup,
  ReactiveFormsModule,
} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-vehicle',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
  templateUrl: './add-vehicle.component.html',
  styleUrl: './add-vehicle.component.scss',
})
export class AddVehicleComponent {
  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private appRef: ApplicationRef,
    private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef
  ) {}

  addVehicleForm = this.fb.group({
    make: [''],
    model: [''],
    year: [''],
    films: this.fb.array([this.createFilmFormGroup()]),
  });

  createFilmFormGroup(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      title: [''],
      releaseDate: [''],
      url: [''],
    });
  }

  get films(): FormArray {
    return this.addVehicleForm.get('films') as FormArray;
  }

  addFilm() {
    this.films.push(this.createFilmFormGroup());
  }

  removeFilm(index: number) {
    this.films.removeAt(index);

    this.addVehicleForm.reset(this.addVehicleForm.value);

    // not working
    // this.addVehicleForm.updateValueAndValidity();

    // not working
    // this.appRef.tick();

    //not woorking
    // this.cdr.detectChanges();
  }
}
```

```
<div>
  <h1>Add Vehicle</h1>
  <form [formGroup]="addVehicleForm">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="make">Vehicle Make</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        class="form-control"
        id="make"
        formControlName="make"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="model">Vehicle Model</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        class="form-control"
        id="model"
        formControlName="model"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="ManufactureYear">Manufacture year</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        class="form-control"
        id="ManufactureYear"
        formControlName="year"
      />
    </div>

    <div style="border: 1px solid black; border-radius: 10px; padding: 10px">
      <div formArrayName="films">
        @for (film of films.controls; track $index) {
        <div
          [formGroupName]="$index"
          style="
          border-bottom: 1px solid #222;
          padding: 10px;
          margin-bottom: 10px;
        "
        >
          <input type="hidden" name="id" formControlName="id" />
          <div class="form-group">
            <label [for]="'title' + $index">Title</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              class="form-control"
              [id]="'title' + $index"
              formControlName="title"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label [for]="'releaseDate' + $index">Release Date</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              class="form-control"
              [id]="'releaseDate' + $index"
              formControlName="releaseDate"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label [for]="'url' + $index">URL</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              class="form-control"
              [id]="'url' + $index"
              formControlName="url"
            />
          </div>
          <button type="button" (click)="removeFilm($index)">
            Remove Film
          </button>
        </div>
        }
      </div>
      <button type="button" (click)="addFilm()">Add Film</button>
    </div>
  </form>

  <pre>
  {{ addVehicleForm.value | json }}
</pre
  >
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `track $index` is not always a good practice (cf: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/53800).

It's usually better to track by a "stable" value. Basically the index changes will prevent the DOM to know exactly which element has been changed (it depends how you bind your value to the DOM but it's the idea).

Usually the easiest way is to add a unique identifier to your object and to track by using it.

For example, you can define an index variable or generate a random value with any lib:

```
createFilmFormGroup(): FormGroup {
    this.index++;
    return this.fb.group({
      id: [this.index],
      title: [''],
      releaseDate: [''],
      url: [''],
    });
  }
```

And in your html you can track with a dedicated function:

```
getId(film: any) {
    return film.controls.id.value;
  }
```

```
@for (film of films.controls; track getId(film)) {
```

Comment: this is correct, if anyone needs to get rid of `any` keyword from getId function, use `AbstractControl` as the type and then you can use this 
 `getFilmId(film: AbstractControl): string {
    return film.get('id')!.value;
  }`